# Prove/disprove $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}}\frac{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{a^2+4b^2+4c^2}} \le 2$ for $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=3.$ Prove or disprove that
> $$\dfrac{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{a^2+4b^2+4c^2}}+\dfrac{\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b^2+4c^2+4a^2}}+\dfrac{\sqrt{{\color{red}a}}+\sqrt{{\color{red}b}}}{\sqrt{c^2+4a^2+4b^2}}\le 2.$$

For $a=b=c=1,$ LHS $=$ RHS, so, using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$(a^2+4b^2+4c^2)(1+4+4)\ge (a+4b+4c)^2$$
so  we need show
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}{a+4b+4c}\le\dfrac{2}{3}$$
it seems that this inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: I guess you have a typo in the first inequality. The numerator in the last term on the LHS should be $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $u + v \le \sqrt{2(u^2 + v^2)}$, we have
$$\sqrt b + \sqrt c
\le \sqrt{2(b + c)} \le \sqrt{2\sqrt{2(b^2 + c^2)}}.\tag{1}$$
It suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{\sqrt{2\sqrt{2(b^2 + c^2)}}}{\sqrt{a^2+4b^2+4c^2}} \le 2. \tag{2}$$

Using $u + v + w \le \sqrt{3(u^2 + v^2 + w^2)}$, we have
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{\sqrt{2\sqrt{2(b^2 + c^2)}}}{\sqrt{a^2+4b^2+4c^2}}
\le \sqrt{3\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{2\sqrt{2(b^2 + c^2)}}{a^2 + 4b^2 + 4c^2}}.\tag{3}$$
It suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{6\sqrt{2(b^2 + c^2)}}{a^2 + 4b^2 + 4c^2} \le 4. \tag{4}$$

Let $x = a^2, y = b^2, z = c^2$.
We have $x + y + z = 3$. We need to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{6\sqrt{2(3-x)}}{12 - 3x} \le 4. \tag{5}$$

Let $3 - x = 2u^2, 3 - y = 2v^2, 3 - z = 2w^2$. We have
$u^2 + v^2 + w^2 = 3$. We need to prove that
$$\frac{u}{2u^2 + 1} + \frac{v}{2v^2 + 1}
+ \frac{w}{2w^2 + 1} \le 1. \tag{6}$$
This is discussed and proved in
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2195486p16486899.

*Remarks*: We may directly prove (5) using calculus. But my proof is not nice.

Comment: It's Nice solution +1

Answer (score 0):

Some tought  :

Let :

$$f\left(x,y,z\right)=\frac{\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+4y^{2}+4z^{2}}}$$

$$h\left(x\right)=f\left(x,a,b\right)+f\left(a,b,x\right)+f\left(b,x,a\right)$$

Then it seems we have for $a^2=3-b^{2}-x^{2}>0$ and $b\in(1/3,2)$:

$$h(x)\leq \frac{2}{\left(f\left(0,a,b\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\left(f\left(x-1,a,b\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Edit :

We can divide the problem into :

Let the contraint as above and then it seems we have for $a^2=3-b^{2}-x^{2}>0$ and $b\in(1/3,2)$:

$$\frac{\frac{4}{3}+\frac{x}{18}\left(1-x\right)}{\left(f\left(0,a,b\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\left(f\left(x-1,a,b\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\geq f\left(a,b,x\right)+f\left(b,x,a\right)\tag{I}$$

And :

$$f\left(x,a,b\right)-\frac{\frac{2}{3}-\frac{x\left(1-x\right)}{18}}{\left(f\left(0,a,b\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\left(f\left(x-1,a,b\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq 0$$

For an idea of proof for $I$ we have for $x\in[1,a)$ or $x\in(a,1]$:

$$h\left(x\right)=\frac{\frac{4}{3}+\frac{x\left(1-x\right)}{18}}{\left(f\left(0,a,b\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\left(f\left(x-1,a,b\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\geq \frac{\left(h\left(1\right)-h\left(a\right)\right)}{1-a}\left(x-1\right)+h\left(1\right)$$

Then it seems we have with the contraint above :

$$\frac{\left(h\left(1\right)-h\left(a\right)\right)}{1-a}\left(x-1\right)+h\left(1\right)\geq f\left(a,b,x\right)+f\left(b,x,a\right)$$

Last tought with the notation above :

Let $0.85\le b\le 1$ then it seems we have :

$$m(x)(1+(t(1)-m(1))/|1-b|^{1/2})\ge t(x)=f(a,b,x)$$

Where :

$$m(x)=1/2*h(x)*(1+(1-x)/24+(a-b)^2/48+(a-b)/72)$$

Comment: But you need $a=\sqrt{3-b^2-x^2}$ in order to satisfy the contraint $x^2+a^2+b^2=1$. And then $h(1.096)<2$.

Comment: @MartinR My bad and I delete.

Comment: Re your edited answer: Does this prove or disprove the given inequality?

Comment: @MartinR Computation show the inequality is true . Remains a roof. I shall add something if I can .